populating audio source in lamejs
I have this code from the lamejs example:
let channels = 1; //1 for mono or 2 for stereo
let sampleRate = 44100; //44.1khz (normal mp3 samplerate)
let kbps = 128; //encode 128kbps mp3
let mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(channels, sampleRate, kbps);
let mp3Data;

********** this line is stumping me: **********
let samples = new Int16Array(44100); //one second of silence (get your data from the source you have) 
let sampleBlockSize = 1152; //can be anything but make it a multiple of 576 to make encoders life easier
let mp3buf;

mp3Data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {
  let sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);
  mp3buf = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
  if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
    mp3Data.push(mp3buf);
  }
}
mp3buf = mp3encoder.flush(); //finish writing mp3

if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
  mp3Data.push(new Int8Array(mp3buf));
}

let audioBlob = new Blob(mp3Data, { type: "audio/mp3" });

I am not sure how to add my own source/samples: I am using the browser mediarecorder:
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

I have tried to use chunks as the source/samples but I am not knowledgable enough about audio in general so can anyone help me on how to format the data and the underlying reason? I am just so lost as to where to start. Thanks in advance.

This is how I got it to work in case anyone else has the same issue:
let mp3Data = [];
let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

let audioBuffer = await getPCM();
let samples = getSamples(audioBuffer);
let audioBlob = getBlobMp3(samples);


// pcm: pulse-code modulation, used in audio
async function getPCM() {
  // chunks from mediaRecorder
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
  let arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();

  return await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
}

function getSamples(audioBuffer) {
  let channelData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0); // Mono channel (0 for left)

  return float32To16BitPCM(channelData);
}

function float32To16BitPCM(float32Array) {
  let int16Array = new Int16Array(float32Array.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < float32Array.length; i++) {
    int16Array[i] = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, float32Array[i])) * 0x7fff; // 0x7FFF = 32767
  }

  return int16Array;
}

function getBlobMp3(samples) {
  let mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(
    1, // Mono channel
    44100, // 44.1kHz
    128, // 128 kbps for MP3 encoding
  );

  let sampleBlockSize = 1152; // multiple of 576

  for (let i = 0; i < samples.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {
    let sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);
    let bufferMp3 = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
    if (bufferMp3.length > 0) {
      mp3Data.push(bufferMp3);
    }
  }

  let finalBufferMp3 = mp3encoder.flush();
  if (finalBufferMp3.length > 0) {
    mp3Data.push(finalBufferMp3);
  }

  return new Blob(mp3Data, { type: "audio/mp3" });
}

I had to:

get an array buffer from a blob made of audio chunks from mediarecorder
get an audiobuffer from that array buffer using audioContext
convert that audiobuffer from 32bit to 16bit
pass the 16bit array to lamejs to convert to mp3
make another blob from the mp3
pass up the audio blob to the server to be processed.

I am not sure if it is the correct answer but it did work for me. If anyone knows a better way to do this, please comment/answer.
